# Limit on the gremlin Query result set size in cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

in cosmosDB graph i have a vertex named "student" which have the following properties.

query:

`g.V().hasLabel('student').valueMap().limit(1)`

output:

```
{
    "StudentID": [
      10000
    ],
    "StudentName": [
      "RITM0809903"
    ],
    "Student_Age": [
      "ritm0809903"
    ],
    "Student_class": [
      "Awaiting User Training"
    ],
    "Student_long_description": [
      "*******************HUGE STUDENT DESCRIPTION*****************************"
    ]
  }
```

Note: "HUGE STUDENT DESCRIPTION" is a huge description about a student.

- Total number of student vertices available are 9.
- i am using gremlinpython module to hit the query on cosmosdb and fetch the query results.
- but when i try to do valueMap('StudentID','StudentName','Student_long_description') and get all the 9 vertices("g.V().hasLabel('student').valueMap('StudentID','StudentName','Student_long_description')") in output i am only able to see the 7 vertices , but when i exclude the property ""Student_long_description" i am able to see all 9 vertices.
- is it because of the limit on the result set size.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits

- but when i include fold at last ("g.V().hasLabel('student').valueMap('StudentID','StudentName','Student_long_description').fold()") i am able to see all the 9 vertices along with the property ""Student_long_description" but folded.

please let me know is their any option i can use to get all the 9 vertices with all the properties without using fold in the query.

Comment: Are you trying to read all the properties of all vertex?

Comment: No i am taking only few properties

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in TinkerPop that would prevent the return of all results, so i sense this must be some behavior specific to CosmosDB. Interesting question.